# Provide 2 http responses, first will display loading, second will provide computed data

Tags: http, loading, httpresponse

I have an application that takes a long time to compute data & provide results. Ideally I would want to display a loading symbol or something similar, immediately once the page is requested & once the actual computation is completed I would want to display the results. My question is how to go about this because traditionally 95% of time is spent getting the response ready so the loading icon will not be seen untill the response is served completely to the user, by which time displaying the loading icon will be moot because rendering the response is not the problem point, it is the "getting the data" part which is very time consuming.

BTW, I am using java servlets + freemarker.

**TL;DR** Provide intermediate response until the real response is ready to be served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX. That's one of its best use cases. You show the page, make an asynchronous request for the data, show the loading screen, and when the request comes back you show the data.

Comment: I had actually thought about this but this would entail the response to the AJAX request have both Business Logic/Javascript & the Markup. Generally sending business logic in an ajax request is frowned upon, I think.

Comment: It doesn't have to entail anything you don't want it to entail. It's just an HTTP request. It can return JSON data to the page which already contains the JavaScript to process that data into HTML. It can return HTML that just gets shoved into the document. It can contain JavaScript with the data to run. It's up to you.